# iOS Beta Testing Without Annoying Clicks

Tags: ios

I'm seeing a few beta testing issues on iOS.

1. TestFlight requires a Beta Review for external Beta Testers and restricts the speed of updates.
2. Other services require the user to register with them before they can become external beta testers.

What I want - the user gets an SMS with a link, goes there, accepts a trust message with one tap and installs the app. No extra registration. How can we get there?

Answer (score 1):

you can, but only with Enterprise developer license

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight requires Beta Review, but it's not the same review as you upload to the App Store, It's much quicker.

After you pass the review for the first time, the review on each update takes no time at all (as long as the changes you made aren't significant)

So I would go with TestFlight.